# Why I'm getting a null value when querying a model in eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I have a problem where I'm getting a null value when querying a model in eloquent, I have a two models `User.php` and `Project.php`, When I use tinker and use `User.php` to check if the data has a relation to `Project.php` model I got what I want, but when I use the `Project.php` to check if it has a relation to `User.php` I'm getting a null value.

This is my code for `Project.php` :

```php
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    public $table = "project";

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function owner(){
         return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

And this is my code for `User.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    public function projects(){
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

This is my result in Tinker:

[image: Query model User.php to Project.php]

This is the result when I use tinker and query, as you can see my `User.php` has a relation to `Project.php`, But when I use `Project.php` I'm getting null value.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with:

```php
public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Because (quote from the docs):

> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with a `_` followed by the name of the primary key column.

Comment: Thanks, It working now. I'm getting the `user_id` value.

Answer (score 0):

You should use eager loading to load parent relationship like this :

```
Project::with('owner')->first()->owner
```

And confirm that the foreign keys is correct

Comment: `Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/RelationNotFoundException with message 'Call to undefined relationship [users] on model [App/Project].'` Error in tinker? By the way I've change owner to users.